# My program generates 50 random numbers and the first number is between 1 and 2, the second is between 1 and 3.. and the last is between 1 and 50

Tags: python-3.x

But so far I am not getting the output required. I am just a beginner in python.

My code is like this:

```
import math
import random
from random import randint
for i in range(50):
    value = random.randint(1,50)
    print(math.floor(value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a few things wrong here, first it's the range, `range(50)` allows you to go from 0 to 49, second you always look for random numbers between 1 and 50, finally you don't need the `math.floor` since `randint` already generates well...  `int`s, there is a slightly modified version of your script:

```py
import random
from random import randint

for i in range(2, 51):
    value = random.randint(1, i)
    print(value)
```

As a side note, you may consider wrapping your code inside a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-function).

Answer (score -3):

```
from random import randint 

for i in range (1,52):
    x = randint (1,50)
    print (1,x,i)
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: Does that really generate a random number between 1 and 2 in the first iteration? Looks more like [1,50].